# Send and Receive IQ ASMACK Android XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am new to XMPP protocol, i tried to find good examples of sending and receiving IQ packets in XMPP ANDROID, but i failed, I tried using the following chunk of code but it did not help.

**CODE:**

```
final IQ iq = new IQ() {
    public String getChildElementXML() { 
    return "<iq type='get' from='9f30dacb@web.vlivetech.com/9f30dacb' id='1'> <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/></iq>"; // here is your query
    //"<iq type='get' from='9f30dacb@web.vlivetech.com/9f30dacb' id='1'> <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/></iq>";
     }};
    // set the type
iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
// send the request
connection.sendPacket(iq);
```

I tried using this code, but it did not send any message to server. can somebody help me with right piece of code? so that i can send my IQ's to the server and receive the response

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending and Receiving Custom IQ XMPP ANDROID ASMACK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405405/sending-and-receiving-custom-iq-xmpp-android-asmack)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it yet, but try

```
    IQ iq = new IQ();
    iq.setTo("destination@server");
    iq.setFrom("9f30dacb@web.vlivetech.com/9f30dacb");
    iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);        
    iq.setPacketID("1");
    connection.sendPacket(iq);
```

Comment: how about sending basic Message packet, does that work? Just to make sure if server is up and users are connected

Comment: a simple message packate is working, but i am unable to send IQ. i guess there are syntax issues or some logical mistake that i am unaware of

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the correct address of destination,  that includes the resource from destination, like this example

```
iq.setTo("destination@dominio_destination.com/recurso_destination");
```

Now you can send the packet:

```
connection.sendPacket(iq);
```

Comment: @HassaanRabbani- how?