# Sending and Receiving custom XMPP IQs with aSmack on Android

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

**Background:**

I have implemented one to one chat using aSmack for XMPP on Android. I am also able to send and receive IQ messages.

**The issue is:**

I am unable to send and receive custom IQ messages. for example if i want to send an IQ

```
<iq type='get'
    to='ssmack@web.mystudios.com/mack'>
<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
</iq>
```

aSmack works fine for this IQ as it is not custom, but if i change the `name space` here from `disco#items` to `Match` it will not work it will send back server a response stating

```
<error code='503'
       type='cancel'>
<service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
</error>
```

and this response is send from my client. but i tried to debug it, i put break points on all receiving and sending packets code. but it does not enter there.

My code for receiving packet is:

```
connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet p) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String fromName1 = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(p.getFrom());
                    Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + p.toXML() + "] from [" + fromName1 + "]");

                    m1=p.getFrom();


                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            setListAdapter();
                            recieve.setText(m1);
                        }
                    });
```

I guess i need to add some listeners to get the custom response. can somebody guide me through that?

Comment: @Flow i am facing a problem in sending and receiving message on android device from xmpp server using asmack, Can you come over this [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68853/trying-to-learn) to help me, Thanks

Comment: i am facing a problem in sending and receiving message on android device from xmpp server using asmack, Can you come over this [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68853/trying-to-learn) to help me, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code is incomplete. `addPacketListener()` takes two arguments.

I suspect you don't register a provider for the custom IQ on the receiving side, that's why it returns `<service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>`

You may want to read some documentation:

- [Provider Architecture: Packet Extensions and Custom IQ's](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/providers.html)
- [Brief Tutorial on IQ Providers](http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-2702)

Comment: when i try to receive normal IQ using same code. it works. when i try to receive disco#items it works but when i enter custom name space the following error is generated

Comment: how do i register a provider for custom IQ at the recieving side?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [ServiceDiscoveryManager](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/ServiceDiscoveryManager.html) and register your custom namespace like this:

```
ServiceDiscoveryManager sm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
sm.addFeature("your:namespace");
```

Look at [Smack sources](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/extensions/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smackx/iqversion/VersionManager.java), all internal IQ handlers add themselves as feature, match incoming query packets by namespace and build result or error reply.

Comment: can you quote a codded example..? ServiceDiscoveryManager.addfeature?

Comment: and exactly where do i need to call this function. before sending packet ?

Comment: I have add example code, also check link to ServiceDiscoveryManager reference, there is a note where better to call `addFeature`

Comment: The missing feature definition can not cause the described problem.